# get list of all devices using a app on a local network

Tags: android, android-networking

Hi I am trying make an app that detects and allows a user to communicate with other users who are using the same app in the same local network.
So I was thinking, if it is possible to get all ip's and see which are alive, but I ran into 2 problems

1.how to check if a particular ip is alive i.e is there a mechanism to ping in android?

2.and after getting if alive how to check if same app is running on the device.

Another way I was thinking was to set a broadcast to all devices on a particular port, at the same time all apps with the same app will be listening for broadcast and reply. But is this a good idea as port will be hard coded and app will be broadcasting and listening at the same time.
Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can try a third idea of having a server of you app, on which every installed app will send its status, whether user is available or not. Then by checking from server, you can show it to the user who wants to communicate with other users, that who is available for communicating and who is not.

Comment: In case if you want some peer-to-peer connection, you may get network prefix, calculate network host addresses and iterate through all of them, trying to connect to a specific port used by the app